# Django: Key 'urls' not found in <QueryDict: {}>

Tags: django, templates, post, view

what I want to do is to set a parameter in the model.py through the template.

There is a text box on the main_index and I want to click "submit" to POST it to the result page. However the result page cannot receive the POST, that is, is always prints "Not Post!"

Here is the view:

```
def main_index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    cmodel = InfoController.objects.all()
    print "I am at index"
    return render_to_response('infoRetriever/index.html', c)

def results(request):
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        print "Not Post!"
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    cmodel = InfoController()
    metaUrl = request.POST['urls']
    firstList = cmodel.controller(metaUrl)
    print "I am at result"
    for item in firstList:
        print "items: ", item
    return render_to_response('infoRetriever/results.html', { 'firstList': firstList})
```

template:

```
<form action="{% url 'infoRetriever:request_page' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="urls" size="60" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick the data from `request.POST` when the `request.method=='POST'`. That is why you are having `KeyError` because the request method is `GET`. So you can do:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    metaUrl = request.POST['urls']
```

Also make sure you are not redirecting from `request_page` view to `results` view as then the request will no longer be a `POST` request for `results` view.

Comment: Thanks, but it was "if NOT request.method == 'POST':", the result page is not requested in POST...

Comment: Yes as you said request was not `POST` so `POST` dict is empty hence `KeyError`

Comment: So why it is empty? How can I pull the url text out? It should be a POST but now it isn't...

Comment: The `results` view is it associated with url `infoRetriever:request_page`? or are you redirecting may be from `request_page` view to `result` view? Please show your urls also.

Comment: Problem solved, I just had eliminated an intermediate page and it got POST now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Robert That is what i figured out. Check my previous comment.